# Write a XAML - HTML Convertor in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I would like to write a XAML-HTML Converter, which will only handle Bold, Italic, Underline . It should not be too difficult but since I am a beginner I need some help on how can i do this ?

Comment: Is this an exercise or do you have business requirement for it?  If the latter what would that requirement be?  Why would you have such simple content expressed in Xaml in the first place?

Comment: Yes this is a business requirement. I have some text in my text box which can be formatted to bold, italic and underline on click of bold, italic and underline buttons respectively  Example: "This is sample text" If i select the above text and click on bold i should get  <b>This is sample text</b>. If i click on italic i should get <i><b>This is sample text</b></i> and same goes with underline. It must also work if i want to remove bold, italic or underline tags

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is to have a look at [the MSDN documentation for the XamlReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). However it means that you need to have the xaml available in plain text - not as baml resource.